# UI Automation - querying cell.name() takes 25 seconds

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

Why does this script take under 4 seconds to complete on my iPhone 6 Plus:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget(); 
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var tableview = window.tableViews()[0];
cell = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[3];
```

but this script takes over 25 seconds on the same device:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget(); 
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var tableview = window.tableViews()[0];
cell = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[3];
UIALogger.logMessage("Cell name: " + cell.name());
```

The problem is clearly something to do with cell.name().

Comment: Add some `NSLog()` statements to see where the tie is. What is `cell.name()`. Also such a compound statement: `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[3];` is clearly a [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation.

Comment: @Zaph Unfortunately this is how the native library works, if you want to access the particular table cell, unless you wrap your application into a library (which I would recommend) you are stuck with messy calls.

Comment: @Cigarillo I honestly don't know why that line takes a long time, UIAutomation in the mobile space is a fairly recent phenomenon, I would guess you are experiencing its relative immaturity. Certain things behave strangely from my experience and there isn't much you can do... you can try UIALogger.logDebug that's what I've always used, you should also say `var cell` though that doesn't really matter

Comment: Is the cell visible?  What do you get from `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].logElementTree()`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you `target.pushTimeout(0);` before querying `cell.name()` and `target.popTimeout();` afterward?